# How to align two unequal sized timeseries numpy array?

Tags: python, alignment, time-series, closest-points

I have two numpy arrays containing timeseries (unix timestamps).
I **want to find pairs of timestamps** (1 from each array) whose **difference** is within a **threshold**.

For achieving this, I need to align two of the time series data into two arrays, such that each index has its closest pair. (In case of two timestamps in arrays equally close to another timestamp in another array, I don't mind choosing either one, as the count of pairs is more important than the actual values.)

So the aligned data set will have **two** arrays of **same size**, plus a smaller array being filled with empty data .

I was thinking of using `timeseries` package and the `align` function.
But am not sure **how to use aligned for my data** which is a timeseries.

Example consider two timeseries arrays:

```
ts1=np.array([ 1311242821.0, 1311242882.0, 1311244025.0, 1311244145.0, 1311251330.0, 
               1311282555.0, 1311282614.0])
ts2=np.array([ 1311226761.0, 1311227001.0, 1311257033.0, 1311257094.0, 1311281265.0])
```

Output sample:

Now for `ts2[2] (1311257033.0)`, its closest pair should be `ts1[4] (1311251330.0)` because the difference is `5703.0`, which is within the `threshold`, and it is the smallest. Now that `ts2[2]` and `ts1[4]` **are already paired** they should be left out of other calculations.

**Such Pairs should be found**, so the Output array might be longer than the actual arrays

> abs(ts1[0]-ts2[0]) = 16060
> **abs(ts1[0]-ts2[1]) = 15820** //pair
> abs(ts1[0]-ts2[2]) = 14212
> abs(ts1[0]-ts2[3]) = 14273
> abs(ts1[0]-ts2[4]) = 38444
>
> ---
>
> abs(ts1[1]-ts2[0]) = 16121
> abs(ts1[1]-ts2[1]) = 15881
> abs(ts1[1]-ts2[2]) = 14151
> abs(ts1[1]-ts2[3]) = 14212
> abs(ts1[1]-ts2[4]) = 38383
>
> ---
>
> abs(ts1[2]-ts2[0]) = 17264
> abs(ts1[2]-ts2[1]) = 17024
> abs(ts1[2]-ts2[2]) = 13008
> abs(ts1[2]-ts2[3]) = 13069
> abs(ts1[2]-ts2[4]) = 37240
>
> ---
>
> abs(ts1[3]-ts2[0]) = 17384
> abs(ts1[3]-ts2[1]) = 17144
> abs(ts1[3]-ts2[2]) = 12888
> abs(ts1[3]-ts2[3]) = 17144
> abs(ts1[3]-ts2[4]) = 37120
>
> ---
>
> abs(ts1[4]-ts2[0]) = 24569
> abs(ts1[4]-ts2[1]) = 24329
> **abs(ts1[4]-ts2[2]) = 5703** //pair
> abs(ts1[4]-ts2[3]) = 5764
> abs(ts1[4]-ts2[4]) = 29935
>
> ---
>
> abs(ts1[5]-ts2[0]) = 55794
> abs(ts1[5]-ts2[1]) = 55554
> abs(ts1[5]-ts2[2]) = 25522
> abs(ts1[5]-ts2[3]) = 25461
> **abs(ts1[5]-ts2[4]) = 1290** //pair
>
> ---
>
> abs(ts1[6]-ts2[0]) = 55853
> abs(ts1[6]-ts2[1]) = 55613
> abs(ts1[6]-ts2[2]) = 25581
> abs(ts1[6]-ts2[3]) = 25520
> abs(ts1[6]-ts2[4]) = 1349
>
> ---

So the pairs are: (`ts1[0],ts2[1]), (ts1[4],ts2[2]), (ts1[5],ts2[4]`)
The rest of elements should have `null` as their pair
The final two arrays will be of size 9.

Please let me know if this question is clear.

Comment: Could you post a few lines of code that create a small example (or made-up) dataset and the result you would expect. i.e. `data_a = np.array([12345, 12846, 789789])` etc. Would help people trying to help you.

Comment: @Neo I realize this is not your post but you need it for something you're working on.  It is not clear in the description exactly HOW the pairs are obtained, as pairs are selected with differences ranging between 1290-15820 in the given example.  That's quite a spread and there are much closer pairs than those selected.  I understand removing the pairs once obtained but beyond that this question can't be answered with the info given.

Answer (score 2):

Solution using `numpy Mask arrays` output aligned Timeseries(`_ts1`, `_ts2`).
The Result are 3 Pairs and **only** Pairs with Distance 1 can be used to align the Timeseries therfore Threshold=1.

```
def compute_diffs(threshold):
    dtype = [('diff', int), ('ts1', int), ('ts2', int), ('threshold', int)]
    diffs = np.empty((ts1.shape[0], ts2.shape[0]), dtype=dtype)
    pairs = np.ma.make_mask_none(diffs.shape)

    for i1, t1 in enumerate(ts1):
        for i2, t2 in enumerate(ts2):
            diffs[i1, i2] = (abs(t1 - t2), i1, i2, abs(i1-i2))

        d1 = diffs[i1][diffs[i1]['threshold'] == threshold]
        if d1.size == 1:
            (diff, y, x, t) = d1[0]
            pairs[y, x] = True
    return diffs, pairs
```

---

```
def align_timeseries(diffs):
    def _sync(ts, ts1, ts2, i1, i2, ii):
        while i1 < i2:
            ts1[ii] = ts[i1]; i1 +=1
            ts2[ii] = DTNULL
            ii += 1
        return ii, i1

    _ts1 = np.array([DTNULL]*9)
    _ts2 = np.copy(_ts1)
    ii = _i1 = _i2 = 0

    for n, (diff, i1, i2, t) in enumerate(np.sort(diffs, order='ts1')):
        ii, _i1 = _sync(ts1, _ts1, _ts2, _i1, i1, ii)
        ii, _i2 = _sync(ts2, _ts2, _ts1, _i2, i2, ii)

        if _i1 == i1:
            _ts1[ii] = ts1[i1]; _i1 += 1
            _ts2[ii] = ts2[i2]; _i2 += 1
            ii += 1

    ii, _i1 = _sync(ts1, _ts1, _ts2, _i1, ts1.size, ii)
    return _ts1, _ts2
```

---

main:

```
diffs, pairs = compute_diffs(threshold=1)
print('diffs[pairs]:{}'.format(diffs[pairs]))
_ts1, _ts2 = align_timeseries(diffs[pairs])
pprint(ts1, ts2, _ts1, _ts2)
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> diffs[pairs]:[(15820, 0, 1) ( 5703, 4, 2) ( 1290, 5, 4)]
>            ts1                  ts2                    _ts1          diff          _ts2
> 0: 2011-07-21 12:07:01  2011-07-21 07:39:21     ---- -- -- -- -- --  ----   2011-07-21 07:39:21
> 1: 2011-07-21 12:08:02  2011-07-21 07:43:21     2011-07-21 12:07:01 15820   2011-07-21 07:43:21
> 2: 2011-07-21 12:27:05  2011-07-21 16:03:53     2011-07-21 12:08:02  ----   ---- -- -- -- -- --
> 3: 2011-07-21 12:29:05  2011-07-21 16:04:54     2011-07-21 12:27:05  ----   ---- -- -- -- -- --
> 4: 2011-07-21 14:28:50  2011-07-21 22:47:45     2011-07-21 12:29:05  ----   ---- -- -- -- -- --
> 5: 2011-07-21 23:09:15  ---- -- -- -- -- --     2011-07-21 14:28:50  5703   2011-07-21 16:03:53
> 6: 2011-07-21 23:10:14  ---- -- -- -- -- --     ---- -- -- -- -- --  ----   2011-07-21 16:04:54
> 7: ---- -- -- -- -- --  ---- -- -- -- -- --     2011-07-21 23:09:15  1290   2011-07-21 22:47:45
> 8: ---- -- -- -- -- --  ---- -- -- -- -- --     2011-07-21 23:10:14  ----   ---- -- -- -- -- --
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: What is DTNULL? variable isn't introduced in the scope of the question/answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean with aligning timestamps. But you can use the time module to represent timestamps as floats or integers. In a first step you can convert any userformat to an array defined by `time.struct_time`. In a second step you can convert this to seconds form start of the epoche. Then you have integervalues to do calculations with the timestamps.

How to convert user format using `time.strptime()`  is well explained in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html):

```
    >>> import time
    >>> t = time.strptime("30 Nov 00", "%d %b %y")
    >>> t
    time.struct_time(tm_year=2000, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=30, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0,
             tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=335, tm_isdst=-1)
    >>> time.mktime(t)
    975538800.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the small mistakes in the question, I could guess what the problem was really about.

What you are looking at is a classic example of the [Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). Scipy provides you with an implementation of [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), check the doc [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment.html). It doesnt have to be timestamps, can be any number (integer or float).

The below snippet will work with 2 numpy arrays of different sizes along with a threshold to give you either the cost array (filtered by threshold) or the index pairs corresponding to the 2 numpy arrays (again, pairs who's cost is filtered by the threshold).

The comments will walk you through, using the given timestamp arrays as example.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment


def closest_pairs(inp1, inp2, threshold=np.inf):
    cost = np.zeros((inp1.shape[0], inp2.shape[0]), dtype=np.int64)

    for x in range(ts1.shape[0]):
        for y in range(ts2.shape[0]):
            cost[x][y] = abs(ts1[x] - ts2[y])

    print(cost)
    # cost for the above example:
    # [[16060 15820 14212 14273 38444]
    # [16121 15881 14151 14212 38383]
    # [17264 17024 13008 13069 37240]
    # [17384 17144 12888 12949 37120]
    # [24569 24329  5703  5764 29935]
    # [55794 55554 25522 25461  1290]
    # [55853 55613 25581 25520  1349]]

    # hungarian algorithm implementation provided by scipy
    row_ind, col_ind = linear_sum_assignment(cost)
    # row_ind = [0 1 3 4 5], col_ind = [1 0 3 2 4] 
    # where (ts1[5] - ts2[4]) = 1290

    # if you want the distances only
    out = [item 
           for item in cost[row_ind, col_ind] 
           if item < threshold]

    # if you want the pair of indices filtered by the threshold
    pairs = [(row, col) 
             for row, col in zip(row_ind, col_ind) 
             if cost[row, col] < threshold]

    return out, pairs


if __name__ == '__main__':
    out, pairs = closest_pairs(ts1, ts2, 6000)
    print(out, pairs)
    # out = [5703, 1290] 
    # pairs = [(4, 2), (5, 4)]

    out, pairs = closest_pairs(ts1, ts2)
    print(out, pairs)
    # out = [15820, 16121, 12949, 5703, 1290] 
    # pairs = [(0, 1), (1, 0), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to have your time series pairs, I'll advise you to first compute your pairs of indices (`get_pairs`). And then to compute your pair of time series (`get_tspairs`).

In `get_pairs`, I first compute a matrix `m` which represents the difference of each points between the two time series. So the shape's matrix is `(len(ts1), len(ts2))`. Then I choose the smallest distance among all. In order not to choose several times the same index, I set to `np.inf` the distance for the chosen indices. I continue this process till we can not choose more tuple of indices. If the minimal distance is above the threshold, the process is broken.

Once I got my pairs of indices, I call `get_tspairs` in order to generate pairs of time series. The first step here is to join the time series with the selected tuple of indices, then to add the indices that were not chosen and associate them with `None` (equivalent of NULL in Python).

Which gives:

```
import numpy as np
import operator

ts1=np.array([ 1311242821.0, 1311242882.0, 1311244025.0, 1311244145.0, 1311251330.0, 
               1311282555.0, 1311282614.0])
ts2=np.array([ 1311226761.0, 1311227001.0, 1311257033.0, 1311257094.0, 1311281265.0])

def get_pairs(ts1, ts2, threshold=np.inf):
    m = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(ts1, ts2))
    indices = []
    while np.ma.masked_invalid(m).sum() != 'masked':
        ind = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(m), m.shape)
        if m[ind] < threshold:
            indices.append(ind)
            m[:,ind[1]] = np.inf
            m[ind[0],:] = np.inf
        else:
            m= np.inf
    return indices

def get_tspairs(pairs, ts1, ts2):
    ts_pairs = [(ts1[p[0]], ts2[p[1]]) for p in pairs]
    
    # We separate the selected indices from ts1 and ts2, then sort them
    ind_ts1 = sorted(map(operator.itemgetter(0), pairs))
    ind_ts2 = sorted(map(operator.itemgetter(1), pairs))
    
    # We only keep the non-selected indices
    l1 = np.delete(np.arange(len(ts1), dtype=np.int64), ind_ts1)
    l2 = np.delete(np.arange(len(ts2), dtype=np.int64), ind_ts2)
    
    ts_pairs.extend([(ts1[i], None) for i in l1])
    ts_pairs.extend([(ts2[i], None) for i in l2])
    
    return ts_pairs
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pairs = get_pairs(ts1, ts2)
    print(pairs)
    # [(5, 4), (4, 2), (3, 3), (0, 1), (1, 0)]
    
    ts_pairs = get_tspairs(pairs, ts1, ts2)
    print(ts_pairs)
    # [(1311282555.0, 1311281265.0), (1311251330.0, 1311257033.0), (1311244145.0, 1311257094.0), (1311242821.0, 1311227001.0), (1311242882.0, 1311226761.0), (1311244025.0, None), (1311282614.0, None), (1311257033.0, None)]
```

Comment: There's a typo at the end of the line: "l2 = np.delete(np.arange(len(ts2), dtype=np.int64), ind_ts1)"; it should be *ind_ts2* and not *ind_ts1*.

Comment: Fixed, thanks @jointfull

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got your question right. If so and assuming that your data is already sorted you can do that in one pass when using iterators. simply adapt the example to your needs.

---

EDIT:
@jointful found a bug - when catching the StopIteration one value may be "processed", it is neither output nor left in the iterators. Here is the fixed ode.

```
left = iter(range(15, 60, 3))
right = iter(range(0, 50, 5))

try:
    i = next(left)
    j = next(right)
    while True:
        if abs(i-j) < 1:
            print("pair", i, j)
            i = j = None
            i = next(left)
            j = next(right)
        elif i <= j:
            print("left", i, None)
            i = None
            i = next(left)
        else:
            print("right", None, j)
            j = None
            j = next(right)
except StopIteration:
    pass
# one iterator might have succeeded
if i is not None:
    print("left", i, None)
if j is not None:
    print("right", None, j)
# one of the iterators may have leftover elements
for i in left:
    print("left", i, None)
for j in right:
    print("right", None, j)
```

prints

```
right None 0
right None 5
right None 10
pair 15 15
left 18 None
right None 20
left 21 None
left 24 None
right None 25
left 27 None
pair 30 30
left 33 None
right None 35
left 36 None
left 39 None
right None 40
left 42 None
pair 45 45
left 48 None
left 51 None
left 54 None
left 57 None
```

Comment: You have a bug.. you're missing 48 on the left.. (the stop iteration always misses the other one that is in the barrel)

Answer (score 0):

You have two sorted lists of timestamps, and you need to merge them into one, keeping the elements of each list separate from each other,  calculating the difference when there is a switch or change of list.

My first solution is **without using numpy**, and consists in 1) adding to each element the id of the list it belongs to, 2) sort by timestamp, 3) group by list id, 4) construct the new list separating each element and calculating the difference when needed:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

ts1 = np.array([1311242821.0, 1311242882.0, 1311244025.0, 1311244145.0, 1311251330.0, 1311282555.0, 1311282614.0])               
ts2 = np.array([1311226761.0, 1311227001.0, 1311257033.0, 1311257094.0, 1311281265.0])

def without_numpy():
    # 1) Add the list id to each element
    all_ts = [(_, 0) for _ in ts1] + [(_, 1) for _ in ts2] 
    merged_ts = [[], [], []]
    # 2) Sort by timestamp and 3) Group by list id
    groups = groupby(sorted(all_ts), key=itemgetter(1))
    # 4) Construct the new list
    diff = False
    for key, g in groups:
        group = list(g)
        ### See Note    
        for ts, k in group:
            if diff:
                merged_ts[key] = merged_ts[key][:-1]
                merged_ts[2][-1] = abs(end - ts)
                diff = False
            else:
                merged_ts[not key].append(None)
                merged_ts[2].append(None)
            merged_ts[key].append(ts)
        end = ts
        diff = True
    return merged_ts
```

**Using numpy**, the procedure is a little different, and consists in 1) adding to each element the id of the list it belongs to and some helper indices, 2) sort by timestamp, 3) flag each switch or change of list, 4) do a sum scan of the previous flags, 5) calculate the proper index of each element in the merged list:

```
import numpy as np

ts1 = np.array([1311242821.0, 1311242882.0, 1311244025.0, 1311244145.0, 1311251330.0, 1311282555.0, 1311282614.0])
ts2 = np.array([1311226761.0, 1311227001.0, 1311257033.0, 1311257094.0, 1311281265.0])

    def with_numpy(): 
        dt = np.dtype([('ts', np.float), ('key', np.int), ('idx', np.int)])

        all_ts = np.sort(
                np.array(
                    [(_, 0, 1, 0) for _ in ts1] + [(_, 1, 1, 0) for _ in ts2], 
                    dtype=np.dtype([('ts', np.float), 
                                    ('key', np.int),    # list id
                                    ('index', np.int),  # index in result list
                                    ('single', np.int), # flag groups with only one element
                                   ])
                ), 
                order='ts'
            )


        #### See NOTE

        sh_dn = np.roll(all_ts, 1)

        all_ts['index'] = np.add.accumulate(all_ts['index']) - np.cumsum(
                            np.not_equal(all_ts['key'], sh_dn['key']))

        merged_ts = np.full(shape=(3, all_ts['index'][-1]+1), fill_value=np.nan)
        merged_ts[all_ts['key'], all_ts['index']] = all_ts['ts']
        merged_ts[2] = np.abs(merged_ts[0] - merged_ts[1])
        merged_ts = np.delete(merged_ts, -1, axis=1)
        merged_ts = np.transpose(merged_ts)

        return merged_ts
```

Both functions, with or without numpy produce the same result. The printing and formatting could be done as needed. Which function is better depends on the data you have at hand.

**NOTE:** In the case that there is a switch to the other list and after only one value there is a switch back to the previous list, the functions as they are above will only keep the last difference, perhaps losing a smaller difference. In this case you could insert the following sections in the place where the "#### See Note" is:

For the `without_numpy` function, insert:

```
if len(group) == 1:
    group.append(group[0])
```

For the `with_numpy` function, insert:

```
sh_dn = np.roll(all_ts, 1)
sh_up = np.roll(all_ts, -1)
all_ts['single'] = np.logical_and( np.not_equal(all_ts['key'], sh_dn['key']), 
                                           np.equal(sh_dn['key'], sh_up['key']))
singles = np.where(all_ts['single']==1)[0]
all_ts = np.insert(all_ts, singles, all_ts[singles])
```